# How to multi group the records of same field in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

Here is the data of field called Stock item
**Stock Items**
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 3XL
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 3XS
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 4XL
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 4XS
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 5XL
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 5XS
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 3XL
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 3XS
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 4XL
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 4XS
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 5XL
"The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 5XS

This should group with different name like example

**Group Black**

```
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 3XL
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 3XS
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 4XL
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 4XS
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 5XL
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (Black) 5XS
```

**Group white**

```
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 3XL
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 3XS
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 4XL
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 4XS
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 5XL
    "The Gu" red shirt XML tag t-shirt (White) 5XS
```

without selection group
[image]

Like this i kind of report, but this one is edited one

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will have a lot of other samples that will need a better solution but for this specific sample of records you can create formula

```
split(split({stockitem},")")[1],"(")[2]
```

and group on that formula.

Comment: But i need to  display as **Group** those like **black** as separate and same **White** as separate  group, but these are in same field

Answer (score 1):

To expand on CoSpringsGuy's answer, you need to create a formula using what he provided: `split(split({stockitem},")")[1],"(")[2]`.

[image: Formula Workshop]
You can ignore "Sheet1_" in my screenshot - this is because I used Excel to recreate your data source.  If you're using a database this would be the name of the table containing the "stockitem" column.  I just named the formula "formula" for this example, but you can name it whatever you want.

Now you need to add a grouping based on the formula you just created.

[image: Group Expert]

The group name (i.e. Black, White) will be added by default.  You'll also want to add the StockItem column to the Detail section.

The design will look like this:

[image: design]

The result will look like this:

[image: result]

Comment: Good work, i need, group black on same stockitem field and group white on starting of white. might sub report might help for me. i think so. check i change how my data should print

Comment: No problem.  You just need to edit the Detail section of the report.  Where I show the design, remove the @formula field from the section labeled "D".  Then move the "StockItem" field over to the left where you want it.  Then as the price and tax fields to the Detail section where you want them.

Comment: @Clay .. Thanks for brining detail and clarity to my suggestion. I have been away from the PC since I posted my response. FussionWeb If this answer solves your probem please mark Clays answer as your solution. He put a lot more time in this than I did.